# How to make a left button in ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm looking on how to make an left button in the ActionBar like the image below :

[image: Action Bar]

With a separation between the title and the button.

I have tried this :

```
  mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  mToolbar.setTitle("Commentaires");
  mToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
```

But how to make the separation, and how to make it clickable ? Thanks

Comment: final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

Comment: That is for the up button, you will also need to specify the parent for this activity in the manifest file,about the title and line,maybe that's an image the whole thing including the line and commentaires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a left button (and not even setLogo) add this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

(this would be your first part)

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

and this to use it:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```